# setting up postfix email forwarding on ec2 when using route 53

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, amazon-route53

I'm trying to make email forwards for my domain on EC2.
I use route 53.

I have added following two lines to /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In the virtual file i have added

```
name@example.com name@gmail.com
```

I then mapped the virtual file:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

However, it is not working.

Do I need to  configure  route 53 in some way  to have  the  forwarding work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mail is not reaching your ec2 instance you need to:

The dns configuration required is that you either have an A record for example.com pointing to your IP, or that example.com has an MX record pointing to an A record that points to your IP.

In addition to that you need to open the appropriate ports in the firewall. That would be port 25 or 587 depending on your configuration.

If mail is reaching the ec2 instance but it isn't forwarding to mail to your gmail account, please provide the relevant bit of /var/log/syslog

Comment: YES! Had not opened port 25. Wow that saved me a lot of pain. Thank you.